# Git is rejecting push, also unable to pull because of unrelated histories

Tags: git, github

After my commit, I try to push to Github repo:

```
PS C:\Users\Kevin\Documents\Projects> git push origin master
To https://github.com/name/first-project.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/name/first-project.
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Then, I try to pull (because that is what it tells me to do).  I get this error:

```
From https://github.com/name/first-project
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

Can someone please help me?  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

The error for the different histories comes from your local repo and the remote (on GitHub) not having the same commit history.  If you initialized a different repo, you may want to just clone the repo from GitHub and then redo any changes locally on top of the new clone.  This should allow you to then push to GitHub.

Instead if you do have different branches that don't have a common starting point, you could use `--allow-unrelated-histories`, but this should be used with caution and in only specific scenarios when you have different starting points and need to preserve both histories.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
git pull --rebase
```

followed by

```
git push origin master
```